# How to Retrieve innerhtml in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, innerhtml, angular-dart

I'm tinkering with the code from the Angular Dart tutorial to make use of the Tooltip class. Rather than have the text for the tooltip in the Dart file, I want to place it in the html file. I've tried

```dart
dom.Element footnote;
footnote = querySelector("#fn1");
htext = footnote.innerhtml;
```

This code is in the Tooltip class. I get warnings on the last two lines and the Dart doesn't run nor does it throw an error. How do I retrieve HTML from the main html file (i.e., not from a component html file)?

The original code is from [the angular dart website tutorial, chapter four.](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/) The unchanged code doesn't build cleanly, but it doesn't appear to affect it operation. This is a known bug for which there is an open issue.

#### pub build output

```dart
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Compiling tutorial|web/main.dart... 
[Dart2JS on tutorial|web/main.dart]:
1 warning(s) suppressed in package:tutorial.
[Info from Dart2JS]:
Took 0:00:11.779928 to compile tutorial|web/main.dart.
Built 182 files to "build".
```

This output is with the last line commented out

#### tooltip.dart

```dart
library tooltip;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
@Decorator(selector: '[tooltip]')

class Tooltip
{
  final dom.Element element;

  @NgOneWay('tooltip')
  TooltipModel displayModel;

  dom.Element tooltipElem;
  dom.Element footnote;

  Tooltip(this.element)
  {
    element..onMouseEnter.listen((_) => _createTemplate())
           ..onMouseLeave.listen((_) => _destroyTemplate());
  }

  void _createTemplate()
  {
    assert(displayModel != null);

tooltipElem = new dom.DivElement();


    footnote = querySelector("#fn1");
    htext = footnote.innerhtml;


    if (displayModel.text != null)
    {
      dom.DivElement textSpan = new dom.DivElement()
          ..appendHtml(displayModel.text)
          ..style.color = "white"
          ..style.fontSize = "smaller"
          ..style.paddingBottom = "5px";

      tooltipElem.append(textSpan);
    }

    tooltipElem.style
        ..padding = "5px"
        ..paddingBottom = "0px"
        ..backgroundColor = "black"
        ..borderRadius = "5px"
        ..width = "${displayModel.imgWidth.toString()}px";

    // position the tooltip.
    var elTopRight = element.offset.topRight;

    tooltipElem.style
        ..position = "absolute"
    ..top = "${elTopRight.y}px"
    ..left = "${elTopRight.x + 10}px";

    // Add the tooltip to the document body. We add it here because we need to position it
    // absolutely, without reference to its parent element.
    dom.document.body.append(tooltipElem);
  }

   void _destroyTemplate()
  {
    tooltipElem.remove();
  }
}

class TooltipModel
{
  final String text;
  final int imgWidth;

  TooltipModel(this.text, this.imgWidth);
}
```

As you can see, I'm not using the html yet. I'm trying to get it to work one step at a time.

#### index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Chapter Four - A Simple Recipe Book</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <recipe-book></recipe-book>

  <div id="fn1">
    <h2>Citation</h2>
    <p>source specification</p>
    <p>additional information</p>
  </div>

  <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the div with the id fn1.

### Answer

To summarize Günter Zöchbauer answers, I made the following changes to get it to work:

```dart
footnote = dom.querySelector("#fn1");
String htext = footnote.innerHtml;
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain much information. Which warnings do you get? Where is the element with the id `fn1`. Where have you placed the code shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `import 'dart:html' as dom;` which means that `querySelector` (without qualifier) can't be found or is used from another unqualified import if found.
With

```dart
footnode = dom.querySelector("#fn1");
// or 
footnode = dom.document.querySelector("#fn1");
```

the whole document is searched except the content of shadow DOMs. If you want to search the shadow DOMs too you can use

```dart
footnote = dom.document.querySelector("* /deep/ #fn1");
```

or

```dart
footnote = dom.document.querySelector("* >>> #fn1");
```

The 2nd version is the newest but I don't know which browsers or polyfills support it yet.

Comment: I tried the first version and still got the warning. I'm using the Chrome browser Version 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit) on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: We're making progress. When I use footnote = dom.document.querySelector("* /deep/ #fn1");, I don't get any warnings from pub build. When I uncomment htext = footnote.innerhtml;, I get two warnings. I've done a search on how to retrieve innerhtml with angualrdart and nothing pertinent comes up. Do you know of any documentation?

Comment: The better the information you provide the easier to help ;-) If the HTML looks like shown in your question you don't need `* /deep/` but it doesn't hurt either (maybe performance a bit). Again it would be easier if you had provided which warnings you get but I assume changing `innerhtml` to `innerHtml` should fix it.

Comment: Changing it to innerHtml reduced the warning from two to one. I'd be glad to show the warnings if I knew how. All I get is the output I showed above.

Comment: You seem not to declare a variable. try `var htext = footnote.innerHtml;` What development environment are you using. DartEditor should show you these problems before you even execute or build.

Comment: That did it. Sorry for the noob errors. I'm using PHPStorm as an IDE. I'll eventually move to RubyMine when I incorporate it into my RoR application. Is there any way to 'unsupress' warnings? I didn't see any such option on pub build when I searched for it.

Comment: You can use the analyzer manually with `pub global activate tuneup` to install it and run `tuneup` in your Dart project directory. or `pub global activate analyzer` and `analyzer bin/somedart.dart`. You need to add the `~/.pub-cache/bin` directory to your `PATH` variable.